# Ionic 3: Events not working from app component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I want to publish an event from the app component to any page that is going to subscribe that event.

(src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, App, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp{

    logged: boolean = true; // Just for example    

    constructor(app: App, events: Events){
        this.events.publish('app:user', this.logged);
    }
}
```

(src/pages/sandbox/sandbox.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-sandbox',
    templateUrl: 'sandbox.html',
})

export class SandboxPage{

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public events: Events) {

        console.log('Subscribing the event!');
        this.events.subscribe('app:user', logged => {
            console.info(logged);
        });
    }
}
```

Nothing is happening. I do not get the console log output, nor any errors. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: you are going from MyApp to SandboxPage

Comment: @Utpaul: Yes, I want MyApp to transmit data to the SandboxPage.

Comment: You need to emit something in order to receive (subscribe). Try to move the subscribe from constructor to lifecycle events.

Comment: @August Am I not with the variable "this.logged". I want to send that boolean to the SandboxPage, or any other variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow I got it working with this method, but I have to believe there should be something better.

(src/app/app.component.ts)

```
this.events.subscribe('app:getUser', () => {
    console.log('Publish the event!');
    this.events.publish('app:sendUser', true);
});
```

(src/pages/sandbox/sandbox.ts)

```
console.log('Subscribing the event!');
this.events.subscribe('app:sendUser', logged => {
    console.info(logged);
});

this.events.publish('app:getUser');
```